# How do I make multiple fetch calls without getting 429 error?

Tags: javascript, promise

I came across a problem in a book which I can't seem to figure out. Unfortunately, I don't have a live link for it, so if anyone could help me with my approach to this theoretically, I'd really appreciate it.

The process:

- I get from a fetch call an array of string codes (`["abcde", "fghij", "klmno", "pqrst"]`).
- I want to make a call to a link with each string code. 
  example:

```
fetch('http://my-url/abcde').then(res => res.json()).then(res => res).catch(error => new Error(`Error: ${error}`)); // result: 12345
fetch('http://my-url/fghij').then(res => res.json()).then(res => res).catch(error => new Error(`Error: ${error}`)); // result: 67891
...etc
```

- Each of the calls is going to give me a number code, as shown.
- I need to get the highest number of the 5 and get its afferent string code and make another call with that.

"abcde" => 1234

"fghij" => 5314

"klmno" => 3465

"pqrst" => 7234 <--- winner

```
fetch('http://my-url/pqrst').then(res => res.json()).then(res => res).catch(error => new Error(`Error: ${error}`));
```

What I tried:

```
let codesArr = []; // array of string codes
let promiseArr = []; // array of fetch using each string code in `codesArr`, meant to be used in Promise.all()
let codesObj = {}; // object with string code and its afferent number code gotten from the Promise.all()

fetch('http://my-url/some-code')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => codesArr = res) // now `codesArr` is ["abcde", "fghij", "klmno", "pqrst"]
.catch(error => new Error(`Error: ${error}`);

for(let i = 0; i < codesArr.length; i++) {  
      promiseArr.push(
         fetch(`http://my-url/${codesArr[i]}`)
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(res => {
               codesObj[codesArr[i]] = res; 
                        // This is to get an object from which I can later get the highest number and its string code. Like this:
                        // codesObj = {
                        //  "abcde": 12345,
                        //  "fghij": 67891
                        // }
               })
              .catch(error => new Error(`Error: ${error}`)); 
               // I am trying to make an array with fetch, so that I can use it later in Promise.all()
}

Promise.all(promiseArray) // I wanted this to go through all the fetches inside the `promiseArr` and return all of the results at once.
      .then(res => {
         for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            console.log(res[i]); 
            // this should output the code number for each call (`12345`, `67891`...etc)
            // this is where I get lost
         }
      })
```

- One of the problems with my approach so far seems to be that it makes too many requests and I get 429 error. I sometimes get the number codes all right, but not too often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you already found out the 429 means that you send too many requests:

> ## [429 Too Many Requests](https://httpstatuses.com/429)
>
> The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate
> limiting").
>
> The response representations SHOULD include details explaining the
> condition, and MAY include a Retry-After header indicating how long to
> wait before making a new request.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
> Content-Type: text/html
> Retry-After: 3600
>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <title>Too Many Requests</title>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <h1>Too Many Requests</h1>
>     <p>I only allow 50 requests per hour to this Web site per
>     logged in user. Try again soon.</p>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> Note that this specification does not define how the origin server
> identifies the user, nor how it counts requests. For example, an
> origin server that is limiting request rates can do so based upon
> counts of requests on a per-resource basis, across the entire server,
> or even among a set of servers. Likewise, it might identify the user
> by its authentication credentials, or a stateful cookie.
>
> Responses with the 429 status code MUST NOT be stored by a cache.

To handle this issue you should reduce the amount of requests made in a set amount of time. You should iterate your codes with a delay, spacing out the request by a few seconds. If not specified in the API documentation or the 429 response, you have to use trial and error approach to find a delay that works. In the example below I've spaced them out 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).

The can be done by using the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to execute some piece of code later, [combine this with a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Creating_a_Promise_around_an_old_callback_API) to create a `sleep` function. When iterating the initially returned array, make sure to `await sleep(2000)` to create a 2 second delay between each iteration.

An example could be:

```js
const fetch = createFetchMock({
  "/some-code": ["abcde", "fghij", "klmno", "pqrst"],
  "/abcde": 12345,
  "/fghij": 67891,
  "/klmno": 23456,
  "/pqrst": 78912,
});

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
(async function () {
  try {
    const url = "https://my-url/some-code";
    console.log("fetching url", url);
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const codes = await response.json();
    console.log("got", codes);
    
    const codesObj = {};
    for (const code of codes) {
      await sleep(2000);
      
      const url = `https://my-url/${code}`;
      console.log("fetching url", url);
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const value = await response.json();
      console.log("got", value);
      
      codesObj[code] = value;
    }
    
    console.log("codesObj =", codesObj);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();


// fetch mocker factory
function createFetchMock(dataByPath = {}) {
  const empty = new Blob([], {type: "text/plain"});
  
  const status = {
    ok:       { status: 200, statusText: "OK"        },
    notFound: { status: 404, statusText: "Not Found" },
  };
  
  const blobByPath = Object.create(null);
  for (const path in dataByPath) {
    const json = JSON.stringify(dataByPath[path]);
    blobByPath[path] = new Blob([json], { type: "application/json" });
  }
  
  return function (url) {
    const path = new URL(url).pathname;
    const response = (path in blobByPath)
      ? new Response(blobByPath[path], status.ok)
      : new Response(empty, status.notFound);
    return Promise.resolve(response);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case... You should run and wait each `fetch` run finish before run new `fetch` by using `async/await`

```
runFetch = async (codesArr) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < codesArr.length; i++){
    const rawResponse = await fetch(`http://my-url/${codesArr[i]}`);
    const codeResponse = rawResponse.json();
    console.log(rawResponse);
    codesObj[codesArr[i]] = codeResponse;
  }
}
```

hope that help you.